# I2C 5V ↔ 3.3V Interface Chip

Tags: i2c, bidirectional

Does the classical 5 V ↔ 3.3 V [bidirectional MOSFET interfacing solution](http://www.kip.uni-heidelberg.de/lhcb/Publications/external/AN97055.pdf) exist as a DIP package? Or is the common way to place discrete MOSFETs in your circuit? In that case, what are some common low cost through-hole devices that you can recommend for this application?

I realize this question has been asked in a few variations already, but I'm looking for practical implementation guidance here.

Comment: Use dual MOSFETs, easy to implement. Check [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/blog/logic-level-shifting-basics) Digikey article for further information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [NXP P82B96](https://web.archive.org/web/20160506195119/https://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/P82B96.pdf) bidirectional I2C buffer IC comes in DIP8, among other packages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some people do use discrete MOSFETs; for example, the [Sparkfun Logic Level Converter](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8745).

There are a few ICs that do bidirectional I2C interfacing, but as far as I know they are all surface-mount.
The [Bi-directional 3.3v <-> 5v level shifting...](http://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?p=16942) thread mentions a few of them.
Alas, I don't know of any that are in a DIP package.

Pretty much any nFET can handle the relatively low power and speed required for I2C interfacing; the critical spec seems to be "Vgs(th)".
Sparkfun uses a BSS138, a low-cost surface-mount nFET with Vgs(th) of 1.5 V at 1 mA.

Answer (score 1):

TI Makes a part that will do this:

[TXS0102](http://www.ti.com/product/txs0102) - 2-bit bi-directional level translator

Comment: It is NOT in a DIP package.

Comment: Have you used the TXS0102 before? I have a few of them. It seems like they will work find for 3.3V <-> 5V logic level shifting. The one thing that concerns me is that OE references Vcca (3.3V) and I would like to be able to control this via logic level on the 5V side. I suppose I could do this with a pull resistor and a transitor, yes?

Comment: I have used the TXS0102 before, however I don't recall utilizing the OE line. If I remember correctly we tied this pin to Vcca so that the level shifter was always enabled. I think you could drive the OE line with a transistor that was pulled up to 3.3V with a resistor or if your processor has open collector outputs you would just need the pull up resistor to 3.3V.